# File upload to Google Cloud Storage with SignedUrl

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-storage, superagent

I am trying to upload images. I have got my signedUrl to my bucket, but I can't make a proper http put request. I am using the superagent library.

```
const req = superagent.put(url)
  .attach(file.name, file)
  .end();
```

The file object is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File
End the url is the signedUrl from my server.
Without the attachment I can upload an empty file. But with the attachment I get an http 403 error. How can I upload files with this signedUrl?

Comment: 403 codes are when the server understands the call, but some authorization fails. How are you generating the signedURL you are passing to the request?

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same issue because the Content-Type header was missing from my request. Try to add it like:

```
const req = superagent.put(url)
  .attach(file.name, file)
  .set('Content-Type', file.type);
  .end();
```

Hope it helps!